# Java 5 Generics, how to get this sample working

Tags: java

```
public class Calculator<T> {

    public Calculator(){

    }

    public T calculateSum(T a,T b){
        return a; // I need to do something like a + b
    }
}
```

I need to add the T object, I'm restricting the T to be only numeric types. How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: please post what you have done to achieve the above, so that we  can correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generic type arguments *must* be reference types, which excludes arithmetic types. You can give a boxed type such as `Integer` as the type argument, but that will not let you do arithmetic because auto-unboxing only works for *particular*, *specific* boxed types. Even if you restricted the type parameter to be a descendant of `Number`, there would be no way the compiler could be sure that the actual type argument was not some user-defined subclass of `Number` that did not have any auto-unboxing behavior.

More technically, generic types will not let you do anything that you wouldn't be able to achieve by inserting downcasts (and nothing else) in non-generic code. Here, it looks like you want to have a different kind of addition (integer or floating-point) depending on which type the argument is. And there is no way to achieve that solely by inserting casts; you'd have to insert some explicit condition that tested if the values happen to be `Integer`, then `Long`, then `Float`, et cetera. Since this is more complex than a downcast here or there, generics cannot, in principle, to this for you.

This is different from C++ templates, where each instantiation of the template generates (in principle, at least) a separate implementation in the compiler.

What you **can** do is make `Calculator<T>` an abstract class or an interface. Then make concrete subtypes such as

```
 public class IntCalculator extends Calculator<Integer> {
   public Integer calculateSum(Integer a, Integer b) {
     return a+b;
   }
 }
 public class DoubleCalculator extends Calculator<Double> {
   public Double calculateSum(Double a, Double b) {
     return a+b;
   }
 }
```

and so forth.

Comment: I had never noticed how restrictive Number is.  You can't even add Numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Methods (as well as classes) can have type parameters.

```
public class Calculator {

    public Calculator(){

    }

    public <T extends Number > T calculateSum(T a,T b){
        return a; // I need to do something like a + b
    } }
```

Generics are not needed for this exercise.

```
public class Calculator {

    public Calculator(){

    }

    public int calculateSum(int a,int b){
        return a + b ;
    }

    public long calculateSum(long a,long b){
        return a + b ;
    }

    .... you fill in the rest ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your declaration you need to make sure that `T` is always a sub-type of `Number`.

Instead of

```
Calculator<T>
```

try

```
Calculator<T extends Number>
```

then look in `java.lang.Number` and you should find a way to get a value that works with `+`.

Comment: Don't you need to know the concrete type of T to extract the correct value, e.g. `intValue()` ?

Comment: The trouble with that is that none of the `Number` methods that will always give full information. `doubleValue()` can lose bits if the number is a `Long`, and of course `longValue()` will throw away the fractional part of a `Double`. Also, even if the addition could be made to work, it is not possible to construct a new instance of a type parameter to return.

Comment: @Henning Makholm, RTTI can help to some degree if you know that the type comes from a limited set of concrete types.  There is a reliable promotion path from byte to bignum.